# Is there a way to distinguish Analytics logs between Universal and pre-universal code?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to filter the Analytics log by the version of the code who made them.

The goal is to grant that all the Analytics logs id done by the new Universal version.

Comment: Add an annotation or begin using custom variables?

Comment: The goal is to have a report where the old code is used, so adding custom vars can show me where is not used! I like it! Can you put in form in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom variables, or an annotation to indicate the change

Answer (score 0):

[Google has documentation about the differences between classic and universal analytics code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs).

You can test which one is installed using JavaScript pretty easily.

```
if (typeof ga == 'function'){
    // universal analytics
} else if (typeof _gaq != 'undefined'){
    // classic analytics
}
```